# How to delete from list of dictionary if key matches after value check

Tags: python, dictionary

Below is my dictionary

```
myd = [
  {
    'name': 'Abc',
    'id': '101',
    'status': 'Success',
    'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302'  },
  
  {
    'name': 'Abc',
    'id': '101',
    'status': 'Failed',
    'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-21 12:25:32:013302'  },
    
    {
    'name': 'def',
    'id': '102',
    'status': 'Failed',
    'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302'  },
    
    {
    'name': 'ghi',
    'id': '103',
    'status': 'Success',
    'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302'  },
 {
    'name': 'ijk',
    'id': '110',
    'status': 'Failed',
    'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302'  },
 {
    'name': 'ijk',
    'id': '110',
    'status': 'Failed',
    'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302'  }
]
```

- I need to extract dictionary status is 'Failed' only
- If status is 'Success' for `id` which status is 'Failed' then that dictionaries   has to delete from list
- Only Failed has to do add in the dictionary
- If both id's are failed then it can add that dictionary

Expected out

```
myd = [
        {
    'name': 'def',
    'id': '102',
    'status': 'Failed',
    'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302'  },
{
    'name': 'ijk',
    'id': '110',
    'status': 'Failed',
    'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302'  }
]
```

code is below

```
#Remove duplicates
new = [dict(t) for t in {tuple(d.items()) for d in myd}]
for i in new:
  if i['id] ==
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all the ones that succeeded and filter based off that. Using a dictionary with id for the keys and the dict as the values, and just get the values to make the result unique:

```
succeeded = {d["id"] for d in myd if d["status"] == "Success"}
result = list({d["id"]: d for d in myd if d["id"] not in succeeded}.values())
```

Result *(pretty printed)*:

```
[
  {'id': '102',
    'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302',
    'name': 'def',
    'status': 'Failed'
  },
  {'id': '110',
    'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302',
    'name': 'ijk',
    'status': 'Failed'
  }
]
```

Keep in mind this ignores the `lastModifiedDate` but if you want to take that into account it's pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Use [sets](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to check membership for speed. Use [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to first create the list of successful ids. Iterate over you list `myd` and check you conditions; if they are satisfied, then append to the resulting list of ids, **and** add the id to the set of seen ids.

```
successful_ids = {x['id'] for x in myd if x['status'] == 'Success'}
seen_ids = set()

new_d = []
for x in myd:
    if (x['status'] == 'Failed'
        and x['id'] not in successful_ids
        and x['id'] not in seen_ids):
        new_d.append(x)
        seen_ids.add(x['id'])

print(new_d)
# [{'name': 'def', 'id': '102', 'status': 'Failed', 'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302'}, {'name': 'ijk', 'id': '110', 'status': 'Failed', 'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest though not fastest solution is to build a  comprehension of failed ids, and use it to pick one dictionary per failing id

```
failed_ids = list(set([d['id'] for d in myd if d['status'] == 'Failed']))
result = []
for d in myd:
    if d['id'] in failed_ids:
        failed_ids.delete(d['id'])
        result.append(d)
```

or, without comprehension

```
result = []
failed_ids = []
for d in myd:
    if d['id'] not in failed_ids and d['status'] == "Failed":
        failed_ids.append(d['id'])
        result.append(d)
myd = result 
print('results')
print(myd)
```

Using sets for checking already included id will increase performance but would not be noticeable on small lists

Just realized you do not want anything with one or more success records, if so build success list ahead and collect already included into failed id list

```
succ_ids = list(set([d['id'] for d in myd if d['status'] != 'Failed']))
fail_ids = []
result = [] 
for d in myd:     
    if d['status'] not in succ_ids and d['status'] not in fail_ids:
         result.append(d) 
         fail_ids.append(d['id'])
```

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax   failed_ids = list(set([d['id' for d in myd if d['status'] == 'Failed']))

Comment: second one i got empty list

Comment: Well, I gave you an idea asap. I corrected syntax though assumed that you want keep in the result anything that failed at the least once, yet idea is still applicaple

Answer (score 0):

```
counter = 0
newDict=[]

for i in myd:# this for is getting Failed ones into the newDict
    if i['status'] == 'Failed':
        newDict.append(myd[counter])
    counter +=1

counter = 0
for i in newDict:#this for is destroying duplicates
    if i['id'] in newDict[counter]['id']:
        newDict.pop(counter)
    counter +=1
print(newDict)
```

Comment: expected out doesnot match with your output

Comment: it matches now @sim